# Clean architecture and the use of an ORM

Tags: c#, design-patterns, orm, repository

I'm trying to divide my app to 3 layers (Data layer, Domain layer, Presentation layer),
The data layer is using ORM (XPO DevExpress).
The domain layer is 100% agnostic about the database Technology or the ORM Technology. 
The data layer and the domain layer is separated by IRepository interface.

```
public interface IRepository<T>   
{  
    void Insert(T entity);  
    void Delete(T entity);  
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();  
    T GetById(int id);  
}
```

In the presentation layer I have a form contain a grid Control and 3 buttons (Add, Modify, Remove).

My first question is : How to make the grid control refresh when I add or remove a record from the database without reloading all the data?(change notification)

The second question is : how to use the power of an ORM and in the same time make my domain layer agnostic of it.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make the grid control refresh when I add or remove a record from the database without reloading all the data?(change notification)?

Consider domain events and an Event Aggregator.

```
public class ThingCreatedEvent : DomainEvent
{
    public int NewThingId;
}
```

> ...how to use the power of an ORM and in the same time make my domain layer agnostic of it?

Your data layer's doing this:

```
public class XpoRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
}
```

Comment: Where to put XpoRepository<T> ? If you put it in the domain layer then the domain layer is knowing that you are using XPO ORM . I want my domain to be agnostic .(Clean architecture)

Comment: Sure. The interfaces can be in the domain layer or a separate layer of data interfaces, but the implementations will be in implementation-specific assemblies that reference the domain layer and its interfaces. Something like YourApp.Data.Xpo or YourApp.Data.EntityFramework.

Comment: The 'clean' architecture is synonymous with hexagonal/ports and adapters. Your XPO implementation is an adapter that can be plugged into the data access port.

Comment: The Xpo implementation is the adapter but the IRepository<T> still uses the type of data object that references the orm because of its annotations. So that will still break the rule unless the type T is a domain object that is mapped to the orm object.